# Passing variadic arguments in one function to another function in D

Tags: d, variadic-functions

I have a variadic D-style function `foo(format, ...)`, which is a wrapper around `writefln`. I'd like to do something like this:

```
foo(format, <...>) {
    //...
    writefln(format, ...);
}
```

Essentially, passing on the ellipsis parameter(s) to writefln. I understand that this isn't easy/possible in C/C++, but is there a way to accomplish this in D?

Comment: Thanks all, it turns out templates solved the issue very cleanly and elegantly. Added bonus: it doesn't cause any memory allocation, so it can be called from destructors (it's a function from a logging module).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will do it for you:

```
import std.stdio;
void customWrite(Args...)(string format, Args args)
{
    writefln(format, args);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had forgotten that those type of variadics even existed in D. I don't think that [TDPL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321635361) even mentions them. I believe that that makes a grand total of 4 different types of variadics in D.

1. C variadics

   ```
   extern(C) void func(string format, ...) {...}
   ```
2. D variadics with `TypeInfo`

   ```
   void func(string format, ...) {...}
   ```
3. Homogeneous variadics using arrays

   ```
   void func(string format, string[] args...) {...}
   ```
4. Heterogeneous variadics using template variadics

   ```
   void func(T...)(string format, args) {...}
   ```

I believe that [TDPL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321635361) really only talks about #3 and #4, and those are all that I normally use, so I'd have to go digging to figure out how to pass arguments using #2. I expect that it's similar to how you do it in C with #1, but I don't know.

However, it's easy with #3 and #4. In both cases, you just pass `args` to whatever function you want to pass it to. And both allow for indexing and slicing (e.g. `args[1]` and `args[1 .. $]`) as well as having a `length` property. So, they're easy to use, and for the most part, they're the better way to go. The only exceptions that I can think of are if you're calling an existing C function (in which case, you use #1) or if you need heterogeneous templates and can't afford the increase in binary size that templates create (in which case you use #2), which should really only be an issue in embedded environments. In general, #3 and #4 and just plain better solutions.

Comment: Look a bit further down http://www.d-programming-language.org/function.html#variadic : #3 also works with classes.

Answer (score 3):

If you want templates, you can do it like this:

```
auto bar(T...)(T args) { ... }

auto foo(T...)(T args)
{
    return bar!T(args);
}
```

but if you want *run-time* variadic arguments, then you have to do what C does: pass `_argptr` to the "v-version" of your function, e.g. `vprintf`.

Comment: It can be `bar(args)`. You shouldn't need the `!T`.

Comment: @JonathanMDavis: Yes, I realize that. But I always write it explicitly when calling a generic from another because it often makes compiler errors easier to find. (Instead of saying "I can't find a match", it actually tells you what it couldn't match.)

Comment: @Mehrdad: a noteworthy technique!