# Python - passing arguments from one function to a nested function call

Tags: python

I would like to do something similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534425/passing-variadic-arguments-in-one-function-to-another-function-in-d), but in Python.

I want to pass an argument from `function1(abc)` into `function2` as `type = (abc)`.

Pseudocode below:

```
function1 (*args, abc):
    print xyz

    function2(type=abc)
```

Comment: What's wrong with the pseudocode other than the order of arguments in `function1()`?

Comment: python is a dynamic language, so u don't need to pass the type of a object. just using func1(*args) is fine. If u want handle the type, check inside func2, by code: (type(args[1]) == abc)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on your pseudocode:

```
def function2(type):
  print type

def function1(abc, *args):
  print "something"
  function2(type=abc)

>>> function1("blah", 1, 2, 3)
something
blah
```

But based on your linked question, maybe you wanted to pass the varargs:

```
def function2(type, *args):
  print type, args

def function1(abc, *args):
  print "something"
  function2(abc, *args)

>>> function1("blah", 1, 2, 3)
something
blah (1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score -1):

Python is dynamically typed. Though, typecasting is an option.

```
def foo(bar)
  foo_bar(str(bar))
```

http://goo.gl/ixAY3